# What is the meaning of factoring?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.lingq.com/lesson/lesson-18-analyzing-cost-benefits-431411/

However, companies can make an informed decision about an investment by calculating the cost of the investment, comparing it to the potential profit, then ***factoring*** in the amount of time it could take to make that profit.

What is the meaning of **"factoring"** in the above context? What can I use instead of factoring there? and may I have some simple example sentences in plain English about the using of the word **"factoring"**

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/factor says "
factor in /into, to include as an essential element, especially in forecasting or planning:
_You must factor insurance payments into the cost of maintaining a car._"

Comment: So, is "consider" a synonym for "factor in"?

Comment: No. "include as an essential element" is far stronger than "consider".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/factor_something_in_(or_out)):

> **factor something in (or out)**
>
> **phrasal verb**
>
> Include (or exclude)  something as a relevant element when making a decision.
>
> ‘*when the psychological costs are factored in, a different picture will emerge*’

Alternatively you could say "considering" or "accounting for" or "taking XXX into account".  In the context of a calculation, you could just say "including".